# (svn+ssh) getting bash to load my PATH over SSH

Tags: ssh, svn, bash

This problem comes up with me trying to make `svnserve` (Subversion server) available on a server through SSH. I compiled SVN and installed it in `$HOME/bin`. Local access to it (not through SSH) works fine.

Connections to `svn+ssh` fail due to:

```
bash: svnserve: command not found
```

Debugging this, I've found that:

```
ssh user@server "which svnserve"
```

says:

```
which: no svnserve in (/usr/bin:/bin)
```

This is strange, because I've updated the path to `$HOME/bin` in my `.bashrc`, and also added it in `~/.ssh/environment`. However, it seems like the SSH doesn't read it. Although when I run:

```
ssh user@server "echo $PATH"
```

It *does* print my updated path!

What's going on here? How can I make SSH find my `svnserve`? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: When you run 'ssh user@server "echo $PATH"', $PATH gets expanded locally so what you get is PATH on localhost. Try escaping $ like so "echo \$PATH". (doesn't solve your problem, but will help with troubleshooting).

Comment: @lsc: this explains the "echo $PATH" mystery, thanks

Comment: BTW, you may want to update the title to reflect your actual problem (i.e. svn+ssh). That should help you get more relevant answers.

Answer (score 4):

You can try launching the command via a bash using the -l command so it acts as a login shell

```
ssh user@server "bash -l -c 'which svnserve'"
```

As noted in comments I left above, you'll need to escape all $ so variables get expanded on the server and not locally. E.g.:

```
ssh user@server "bash -l -c 'echo \$PATH'"
```

**update:**

Regarding you question on why .ssh/environment does not take effect, I believe the default config for SSHd would be to ignore user environments. You need to specifically enable it in /etc/ssh/sshd_config (or similar) and add:

```
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

**update 2:**

If you do not have access to /etc/ssh/sshd_config, a possible (but not ideal) solution would be to use public-key authentication to launch svnserve on login.

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshtricks

Note that this will affect your ability to log in normally via SSH. To do so, you need to bypass the public key authentication:

```
svn -o PubkeyAuthentication=no user@server
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Unfortunately it still doesn't resolve my original problem which is running `svnserve` via SSH. for some reason ssh ignores my .ssh/environemnt file and every other attempt I try

Comment: @Eli answer updated to address .ssh/environment issue

Comment: Oopps.. just notices that @Dennis has already pointed you that way. Apologies for the repetition.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately since this is a shared server I have no access to /etc/ssh/sshd_config. But from tests I ran it appears this variable indeed isn't set, because ssh ignores my environment file for sure

Answer (score 3):

As it happens, `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are only executed if you're in an interactive shell. When you login through ssh, you are not in an interactive shell, therefore your custom `PATH` definitions are never run. You can associate a script to non-interactive sheels using `BASH_ENV`. Check also `.ssh/environment` which gives you another alternative. The best way to know about this is by doing `man ssh`.

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, but I noted that .ssh/environment didn't work for me. Any tips of what to write there? Also, I was under the impression that .bashrc is included in non-interactive shells. Otherwise, how is my PATH given correctly via ssh? (echo $PATH)?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute an env command:

```
ssh servername "env PATH=$REMOTEPATH which svnserve"
```

Comment: after adding a semicolon before `which`, it says: `which: no svnserve in (/usr/bin:/bin)`

Comment: @Eli: no semicolon - which is an argument to env

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with HostMonster, due to a recent change they made. I found a workraound in an old email thread at http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2007-02/0204.shtml:

On your workstation:

- edit `~/.subversion/config`: locate [tunnels] and add the line ssh=~/svnssh
- create ~/svnssh as in the link:

  `#!/bin/sh`
  `/usr/bin/ssh $1 /<ur_bluhost_home_path>/sshsvnserve -t`
- `chmod +x ~/svnssh`

On your bleuhost account:

- create `~/sshsvnserve`, same content as the link:

  `#!/bin/sh`
  `/<ur_bluehost_home_path>/bin/svnserve $*`
- `chmod +x ~/sshsvnserve`

That's it. The config [tunnels] change modifies the command run by svn when handling the svn+ssh namespace and use ur ~/svnssh script instead. The script invokes ssh and passes in the full path to sshsvnserve on ur bluehost account. And sshsvnserve redirects everything to the full path of svnserve, as u install it. Worked for me, no $PATH required.

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable `BASH_ENV` to `'~/.bashrc'`.

```
ssh servername "BASH_ENV='~/.bashrc' which svnserve"
```

From `man bash`:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a  non-inter‐
>          active  shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes com‐
>          mands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.   After  reading
>          that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
>          in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one  that
>          exists  and  is  readable.

and

> When  an  interactive  shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
>          reads and executes commands from  /etc/bash.bashrc  and  ~/.bashrc,  if
>          these  files  exist.

and

> When  bash  is  started  non-interactively,  to run a shell script, for
>          example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands
>          its  value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name
>          of a file to read and execute.

From `man ssh`:

> Additionally, ssh reads ~/.ssh/environment, and adds lines of the format
>        “VARNAME=value” to the environment if the file exists and users are
>        allowed to change their environment.  For more information, see the
>        PermitUserEnvironment option in sshd_config(5).

From `man sshd_config`:

> PermitUserEnvironment
>                Specifies whether ~/.ssh/environment and environment= options in
>                ~/.ssh/authorized_keys are processed by sshd(8).  The default is
>                “no”.  Enabling environment processing may enable users to bypass
>                access restrictions in some configurations using mechanisms such
>                as LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: @Dennis, yes, this is as I would expect. However, in my case I clearly see that .bashrc is NOT being loaded. Moreover, ~/.ssh/environment is ignored. I can conclude that Bluehost (my server provider) configured it this way, which is very unfortunate.

P.S. the line with BASH_ENV doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get ssh to run commands using the remote path by running:

```
ssh dist@d6 "bash --login -c 'env'"
```

This loads the remote .profile, etc. Here env can be replaced with what ever command you'd like.

I have authorized keys so didn't need a password to run the command or ssh.